A problem of measurability of stochastic kernel
I want to use the stochastic kernel theorem to prove the existence of the following measure: I have a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ and and infinite-dimensional measure space $(A,\mathfrak{B})$ where $\mathfrak{B}$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by cylindrical sets.Now i want to prove that the following  $\mu_{\varrho_{\omega}}$ is a stochastic kernel where $\varrho_{\omega}$ is a postive function and actually is the covariance kernel of the measure $\mu_{\varrho_{\omega}}$ which is a gaussian measure for each $\omega \in \Omega$, now i just need to prove that for each measurable set $ D \in \mathfrak{B}$ $$A \mapsto \mu_{\varrho_{\omega}}(A)$$ is mesurable for each $\omega \in \Omega $. Knowing that the function $\omega  \mapsto \varrho_{\omega}$ is measurable i just need to prove that for each mesurable set $A$ the function $$\varrho \mapsto \mu_{\varrho}(A)$$. For that i was thinking of using weak convergence and the Portemanteau theorem but for that i need to prove that for any mesurable set the border of $A$ has a null measure. So what should i do here ? Can the fact that the measure $\mu_{\varrho_{\omega}}$ is gaussian can be used somewhat ?

I don't fully understand your question, but usually one proves this kind of thing using a monotone class argument.

@MichaelGreinecker , thank you for your comment, i really can't explain anymore because i already daid everything,  if you can tell me what you didn't understand or show me some reference please.

What exactly is $A$? And beides covariances, what are the means?

A is an infinite dimensional space,  you can think of it as the space $S'(R)$ the space of tempred distribution and the measure are all centred meaning the means is zero @MichaelGreinecker

This was asked some days before, no..?: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4922388/measurability-problem
